# The Haskell way to do IO Loops (without explicit recursion)?

Tags: loops, haskell, recursion, monads

I want to read a list of strings seperated by newlines from STDIN, until a new line is witnessed and I want an action of the type `IO [String]`. Here is how I would do it with recursion:

```
myReadList :: IO String
myReadList = go []
where 
    go :: [String] -> IO [String]   
    go l = do {
                 inp <- getLine;
                 if (inp == "") then 
                     return l;
                 else go (inp:l);
                }
```

However, this method of using go obscures readability and is a pattern so common that one would ideally want to abstract this out.

So, this was my attempt:

```
whileM :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> [m a] -> m [a]
whileM p []     = return []
whileM p (x:xs) = do
    s <- x
    if p s
    then do
        l <- whileM p xs
        return (s:l)
    else
        return []

myReadList :: IO [String]
myReadList = whileM (/= "") (repeat getLine)
```

I am guessing there is some default implementation of this `whileM` or something similar already. However I cannot find it.

Could someone point out what is the most natural and elegant way to deal with this problem?

Comment: whileM is in Control.Monad.Loops.

Comment: @n.m. I know, but it does something else. It has a different signature as well: `Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m [a]`

Comment: Your version seems to be close to unfoldWhileM, except you take a list of monadic actions, which yiu don't really need (you generate the list with repeat anyway).

Comment: Reading `Control.Monad.Loops` confirmed by opinion that there are too many forms of loops one can define. I was searching for something like `doWhile :: (a -> IO Bool) -> IO a -> IO [a]`, which I think I used in the past, but didn't find something equivalent. Only `unfoldrM` and friends seem to be that general, but does not separate the guard with the body of the loop. I also wonder if using a loop library makes the code more difficult to read, since most programmers have not memorized the 100 loop variants (even if they will likely guess the intent).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[unfoldWhileM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:unfoldWhileM) is same as your `whileM` except that it takes an action (not a list) as second argument.

```
myReadList = unfoldWhileM (/= "") getLine
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes for abstracting out the explicit recursion as mentioned in the previous answer there is the [`Control.Monad.Loop`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html) library which is useful. For those who are interested [here is a nice tutorial on Monad Loops](http://conscientiousprogrammer.com/blog/2015/12/11/24-days-of-hackage-2015-day-11-monad-loops-avoiding-writing-recursive-functions-by-refactoring/).

However there is another way. Previously, struggling with this job and knowing that Haskell is by default Lazy i first tried;

```
(sequence . repeat $ getLine) >>= return . takeWhile (/="q")
```

I expected the above to collect entered lines into an `IO [String]` type. Nah... It runs indefinitely and IO actişons don't look lazy at all. At this point [`System IO Lazy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyio-0.1.0.4/docs/System-IO-Lazy.html) might come handy too. It's a 2 function only simple library.

```
run        :: T a -> IO a
interleave :: IO a -> T a
```

So `run` takes an Lazy IO action and turns it into an IO action and `interleave` does the opposite. Accordingly if we rephrase the above function as;

```
import qualified System.IO.Lazy as LIO

gls = LIO.run (sequence . repeat $ LIO.interleave getLine) >>= return . takeWhile (/="q")

Prelude> gls >>= return . sum . fmap (read :: String -> Int)
1
2
3
4
q
10
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the effectful streams of the [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.5/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html) package:

```
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S

main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <- S.toList_ . S.takeWhile (/="") . S.repeatM $ getLine
    print result
```

---

A solution that shows prompts, keeping them separated from the reading actions:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <- S.toList_
            $ S.zipWith (\_ s -> s)
                        (S.repeatM $ putStrLn "Write something: ")
                        (S.takeWhile (/="") . S.repeatM $ getLine)
    print result
```